# Just if else show dialog box

Tags: android

```
     String statuss = LoginActivty.review_status;

     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "noman :"+ statuss, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "shah:"+ LoginActivty.review_status
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     if(statuss != "Reviewed"){
            ratingDialog();
            //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Well come back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(statuss == "Not_Review") {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Well come back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

When I statically pass `status` it works perfectly but when I pass `LoginActivty.review_status` dynamically it's not working. Why?

Comment: never compare string using "==", use "equals" method of string. Also make sure you trim the string before you compare. If any further details required, let know.

Comment: @noman-shah read this please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **equals()** instead of **==**

```
    if(!statuss.equals("Reviewed"))
    {
            ratingDialog();
        //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Well come back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(statuss.equals("Not_Review")) 
    {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Well come back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```